# Show script is not working with one button(JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make hide and show script for my info page from one button but here the button is only working for hiding script but when I press it for second time,it display(show) the info but only for a second and ***Poof*** it's gone!

I'm currently learning it so I'm not getting where I'm making mistake!

here's the code
JQuery Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("button.about").click(function(){
    $("div.info").show(1000);
});

$("button.about").click(function(){
    $("div.info").hide(1000);
});
```

button code

```
<button herf="#" class="about">About Me</button>
```

div tag

```
<div class="container-fluid bg1 text-center info">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single click event handler with [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to toggle between them otherwise both will fire at the same time.

```
$("button.about").click(function(){
    $("div.info").toggle(1000);
});
```

```js
$("button.about").click(function() {
  $("div.info").toggle(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button herf="#" class="about">About Me</button>


<div class="container-fluid bg1 text-center info">div</div>
```

---

You can additionaly add [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop the current animation queue.

```
$("button.about").click(function(){
    $("div.info").stop().toggle(1000);
});
```

```js
$("button.about").click(function() {
  $("div.info").stop().toggle(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button herf="#" class="about">About Me</button>


<div class="container-fluid bg1 text-center info">div</div>
```

---

With [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method set the property value as `'toggle'` for toggling those css properties.

```
$("button.about").click(function() {
  $("span.info").stop().animate({
    height: 'toggle',
    opacity:'toggle'
   }, 1000);
});
```

```js
$("button.about").click(function() {
  $("span.info").stop().animate({
    height: 'toggle',
    opacity:'toggle',
    width:'toggle'
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button herf="#" class="about">About Me</button>


<span class="container-fluid bg1 text-center info" sttle="display:inline">div</span>
```

---

Although refer [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) methods.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) does it works with any other JQ effect ?

Comment: @AkritKhanna : for slide use : `slideToggle` , fade : `fadeToggle`

Comment: @AkritKhanna : or with `animate` use the value of property as `'toggle'`

Comment: Is there any way to make the division by default hidden and when we click it then only it will be shown.

Comment: @AkritKhanna : there are several ways , using jQuery `$("div.info").hide()` or using css `<div class="container-fluid bg1 text-center info" style="display:none">`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "button.about" ).click(function() {     
    if($('div.info:visible').length)
        $('div.info').hide( 1000);
    else
        $('div.info').show( 1000);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You registered multiple click events on the same element. One is showing and one is hiding. That is the reason you seeing the weird behaviour.

If you want to implement toggle functionality manually (without using `toggle()` function), below code should will do

```
$( "button.about" ).click(function() {     
    if($('div.info:visible').length) // if visible
        $('div.info').hide(1000);   // hide it 
    else
        $('div.info').show(1000); // show it        
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLewpx0h/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check if the element (div) is visible ?

Like this :

```js
$("button.about").on("click", function(){
 $("div.info").is(":visible") ? 
    $("div.info").hide(1000) : $("div.info").show(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button href="#" class="about">About Me</button>
<div class="info">Info</div>
```